# XQuery syntax error

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

On Oracle 11gR2 I need to retrieve portions of an XML file and create a new one:

```sql
SELECT XMLQUERY
    ('for $e in /edi_l/trader
    where $e//pod="XX999"
    order by $e
    return <pod>{$e}</pod>'
   passing MY_T.XML_FILE
returning content
)
FROM MYTABLE MY_T;
```

The output:

```xml
<pod><trader cdisp="AB1111">
<idimpp num="1234">
<hdr>
<odn>567</odn>
<pod>XX999</pod>
</hdr>
...
</idimpp>
</trader>
</pod>
```

If I omit the tag

```html
<pod></pod>
```

```sql
SELECT XMLQUERY
    ('for $e in /edi_l/trader
    where $e//pod="XX999"
    order by $e
    return {$e}
   passing MY_T.XML_FILE
returning content
)
FROM MYTABLE MY_T;
```

I get errors:

```
ORA-19114: XPST0003
LPX-00801: XQuery syntax error at '{'
4       return {$e}
-              ^
19114. 00000 -  "XPST0003 - error during parsing the XQuery expression: %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred during the parsing of the XQuery expression.
*Action:   Check the detailed error message for the possible causes.
Error at Line: 30 Column: 6
```

Why?

I need to retrieve the data without creating a new external tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the curly braces if you aren't embedding it in your own node:

```
with mytable (xml_file) as (
  select xmltype('<pod><trader cdisp="AB1111">
<idimpp num="1234">
<hdr>
<odn>567</odn>
<pod>XX999</pod>
</hdr>
</idimpp>
</trader>
</pod>')
  from dual
)
SELECT XMLQUERY
  ('for $e in //trader
    where $e//pod="XX999"
    order by $e
    return $e'
  passing MY_T.XML_FILE
  returning content
)
FROM MYTABLE MY_T;

XMLQUERY('FOR$EIN//TRADERWHERE$E//POD="XX999"ORDERBY$ERETURN$E'PASSINGMY_T.XML_FILERETURNINGCONTENT)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<trader cdisp="AB1111"><idimpp num="1234"><hdr><odn>567</odn><pod>XX999</pod></hdr></idimpp></trader>
```

From the documentation on [XQuery expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB5091):

> **Computed (dynamic) constructions** – You can construct XML data at run time using computed values. For example, the following XQuery expression constructs this XML data: **`<foo toto="5"><bar>tata titi</bar> why? </foo>`**.
>
> ```
> <foo>attribute toto {2+3},
>      element bar {"tata", "titi"},
>      text {" why? "}</foo>
> ```
>
> In this example, element **`foo`** is a direct construction; the other constructions are computed. In practice, the arguments to computed constructors are not literals (such as **`toto`** and **`"tata"`**), but expressions to be evaluated (such as **`2+3`**). Both the name and the value arguments of an element or attribute constructor can be computed. Braces (**`{`**, **`}`**) are used to mark off an XQuery expression to be evaluated.

In your first query `pod` is a direct construction and `${e}` is computed, so the braces are necessary. In the second version you're referring directly to `$e` outside any construction, so there is no evaluation, and therefore no braces are required (or allowed).